# MediaPlayer setVolume only works (not muted) when maxed (1.0f, 1.0f)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, volume, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm working on a simple media player and running in to an issue.  When I try to use setVolume it only works/has sound when set to 1.0, 1.0.  If it set it to anything else (e.g. 1.0,0.8; 1.0,0.0; 0.5,1.0; etc.) it's completely muted.  I'm testing on a Nexus 6 (7.0) if this makes any difference.

I've tried putting the setVolume in a few different places thinking maybe it has some effect but nothing seems to change it's behavior.  I've also tried taking out setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); thinking it's messing something up, but no change.

My eventual goal is to have the sound play on the right, then left, then right, then left, etc. bouncing back and forth (specific odd application for this) so I'll be needing to independently adjust the volume on each side quite a bit.

EDIT: Was able to test it on a friend's phone (Galaxy S5 running 6.0.1) and it works perfectly with the same code.  Thoughts?

Thanks!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.IllegalFormatException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// variable declaration
private ListView mainList;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private final String[] listContent = { "Adele", "Moana", "Wanna be Balla", "Move Bitch", "Linkin Park"};
private Button playMusic;
private final int[] resID = { R.raw.adele, R.raw.moana, R.raw.balla, R.raw.ludacris, R.raw.linkinpark};
long startTime;
public volatile Integer i;
private SeekBar duration;
public Integer p;
private static String tag = "EMDR Player is";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Layout thingies
    duration = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.duration);
    playMusic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    i = 0;
    p = 0;

    // Initializing variables


    mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
    mainList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setLooping(true);

    duration.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar duration, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {
            p = progress;
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });




  //  final Integer sleeptime = 1000;
   /* t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while (i == 0) {
                try {
                    mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                    Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
                    mp.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
                    Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
    });*/

    mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            playSong(position);


        }

    });
    mp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.d(tag, "is onError()");
            switch(what){

                case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                    // handle MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN, optionally handle extras
                    handleExtras(extra);
                    break;

                case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                    // handle MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED, optionally handle extras
                    handleExtras(extra);
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    playMusic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        // creates a new onclick listener (does a thing when it's clicked) for our button "playMusic"
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                pauseMusic(); // runs the pauseMusic method
                i = 1;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Elapsed time was " + ((startTime)/1000) + " seconds.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(tag, "is Pause Clicked()");
            }
            else {
                resettobeginningMusic(); // starts the music from the beginning
                startMusic(); // runs the startMusic method
                i = 0;
                Log.d(tag, "is Start Clicked()");

                //toast();
            }
        }
    });}


public void playSong(int songIndex) {
    try{
    mp.reset();// stops any current playing song
    i = 0;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resID[songIndex]);
    playMusic.setText(getString(R.string.button_pause));
    final int test = p;
    final Thread thread = new Thread(new MyRunnable(test));
    thread.start();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Elapsed time was " + ((test)/1000) + " seconds.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mp.start();
        Log.d(tag, "is Initially Started()");
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public void pauseMusic(){

   try{
       if (mp !=null){
           mp.pause();
           startTime=mp.getCurrentPosition();
           playMusic.setText(getString(R.string.button_start));
           i = 1;
           Log.d(tag, "is Paused()");
       }
       } catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalFormatException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

public void startMusic(){
   try{
       if (mp != null) {
           i = 0;
           playMusic.setText(getString(R.string.button_pause));
           final int test = p;
           final Thread thread = new Thread(new MyRunnable(test));
           thread.start();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Elapsed time was " + ((test) / 1000) + " seconds.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           mp.start();
           Log.d(tag, "is Started()");
       }
       } catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalFormatException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

    }


public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    protected Integer mFoo;
    public MyRunnable(Integer foo) {
        mFoo = foo;
    }

    public void run() {while (i == 0) {
        try {
            mp.setVolume(1.0f, 0.0f);
            Thread.sleep(mFoo);
            mp.setVolume(0.0f, 1.0f);
            Thread.sleep(mFoo);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }}
public void resettobeginningMusic() {
    try{
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.seekTo(0);
            Log.d(tag, "is Resetting()");
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


private void handleExtras(int extra){
    switch(extra){
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO:
            // handle MEDIA_ERROR_IO
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED:
            // handle MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED:
            // handle MEDIA_ERROR_UNSPECIFIED
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT:
            // handle MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT
            break;

    }
}

protected void onDestroy(){
    if (mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;

    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Comment: What happens if you use values other than 1.0 but keep both channels the same? As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285581/android-mediaplayer-setvolumeint-int-functionality-stops-playback-when-paramet

Comment: Good find on that other question.  1, 0 / 0, 1 = no sound || 1 , .5 / .5 , 0 = no sound || 0 , .5 / .5, 0 = no sound || 0 , 1 / .5 , .5 = sets the left ear to .5, right ear to 1 with no alternation – just straight music playing, almost like it just defaults to whatever the lowest setting is and keeps it there.  On the galaxy S5 this makes left ear go between .5 and 0ish ( can still hear some music but not very low), right ear (1.0 -> .5) works as intended (so more or less still working as intended overall on the S5, although occasionally there is a loud pop).

Comment: Logcat is showing: W AudioTrack: releaseBuffer() track 0xb04f0000 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting
04-03 19:12:05.383  1843 24762 W AudioTrack: releaseBuffer() track 0xb04f0000 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting
04-03 19:12:05.463  1835 24769 D offload_visualizer: thread enter
04-03 19:12:05.484  1843 24762 D AudioSink: callbackwrapper: EVENT_UNDERRUN (discarded)